# String.Format consider locale or not?

Tags: c#, internationalization

Is it true that String.Format works 2 ways:
   if we use built-in format such as C, N, P.... it will take locale settings into account?
   if we use custom format code such as #,##0.000 it will NOT take locale settings into account?

In my code, I use method like this

String.Format("{0:#.##0,000}", value);

because my country use comma as decimal separator

but the result still is:    1,234.500    as if it consider dot as decimal separator.

Please help!

Comment: Have you ever bothered to look at the documentation of String.Format?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use [CultureInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(VS.80).aspx):

```
value.ToString("N", new CultureInfo("vn-VN"));
```

Using [`String.Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ksz8yb7(VS.80).aspx):

```
String.Format(new CultureInfo("vi-VN"), "N", value);
```

Since you're in Hanoi (from profile), I used Vietnam's code, which is `vn-VN`.

Answer (score 4):

This works. The formatted value is `123.456,789` which is correct per `es-ES`

```
   IFormatProvider iFormatProvider = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES");
   var value = 123456.789001m;

   string s = value.ToString("#,##0.000", iFormatProvider);

   string s2 = string.Format(iFormatProvider, "{0:#,##0.000}", value);

   FormattableString fs = $"{value:#,##0.000}";
   string s3 = fs.ToString(iFormatProvider);
```

Note that the `,` and `.` are using a 'standard' en-US style, but `.ToString()` and `string.Format()` with a format provider does the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your thread uses the correct culture:

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(GetType(FrameworkElement), New FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)))
```

Comment: What happens if you are trying to show numbers, dates, etc. in different cultures in the same thread?

Comment: @ChrisFox it'll depend if you succeed or not. :-)

Comment: I did :-) 1234567890