# How can I get .NET to generate all of the resource files

Tags: .net, resources, globalization

I was looking over the suggestions on this page [Programmatic way to get all the available languages (in satellite assemblies)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/553244/programmatic-way-to-get-all-the-available-languages-in-satellite-assemblies), and decided that this one might fit best:

```
public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> GetSupportedCulture()
{
//Get all culture 
CultureInfo[] culture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

//Find the location where application installed.
string exeLocation = Path.GetDirectoryName(Uri.UnescapeDataString(new UriBuilder(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).Path));

//Return all culture for which satellite folder found with culture code.
return culture.Where(cultureInfo => Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(exeLocation, cultureInfo.Name)));
}
```

So, I created a little test method, but I noticed that one of our resource files does not get generated.

For example, here are the .resx files (located in a separate library project):

- (English) LanguageResources.resx
- (French) LanguageResource.fr-FR.resx
- (Spanish) LanguageResource.es-ES.resx
- (Vietnamese) LanguageResource.vn-VN.resx

So when I go to the executing assemblies bin directory, I only see the following folders: es-ES and fr-FR

Inside the folders, of course, is the resources.dll file.

Does anybody know why the vn-VN folder/resources.dll file is not getting created during the build?  English is not there either, but I half-expect that since it's our default, and 'en-US' is not included in the LanguageResources.resx file name.

I've checked the .csproj file of the library containing the Resource files - and don't see anything obvious.

I did, however, find this in the build log:

- 1>  Culture of "" was assigned to file "LanguageResources\LanguageResource.resx". (TaskId:22)
- 1>  Culture of "" was assigned to file "LanguageResources\LanguageResource.vn-VN.resx". (TaskId:22)

and since neither the English or Vietnamese resources.dll files are being produced I thought this might have something to do with it.

Can anybody shed any light on this? and tell me how to correct the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry,

Actually, with some further digging (apologies, I should have done this before posting) - I found that my System.Globalization.CultureInfo list does not contain a definition for vn-VN.
So then I looked at lists of locales and see mostly only vi-VN, but this post says vn-VN [String.Format consider locale or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1204164/string-format-consider-locale-or-not) is valid.

The bottom line is that the reason the folder and resource file are not showing up on my machine is because the culture is not supported.

Once I changed the filename to use vi-VN instead - it worked.

Does anybody know if vn-VN was ever valid?  or still is?

Thanks!